# Read-only properties, methods and the dot syntax

Tags: objective-c, properties

Please enlighten me on the following:

**Q1** - What is an essential difference between the three declarations below in terms of the code  generated when the property is accessed?

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = getMyProp) NSString* myProp;
@property (readonly, getter = getMyProp) NSString* myProp;
- (NSString*) myProp;
```

**Q2** - Is `[object myProp]` fully equivalent to `object.myProp` in all circumstances (given that the compiler doesn't complain)?

**Q3** - If they are equivalent why is the square bracket form prevalent everywhere, particularly in Apple's sample code?

Thanks!

Comment: `getter = getMyProp` is a sure sign that someone is fighting the standard patterns of the system.   Getter methods should *not* be prefixed with `get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1)  For `nonatomic`, the value will be returned directly. For the implied `atomic`, the return value will be autoreleased (will have been `retain`ed and `autorelease`d prior to return.   For the straight up method declaration, no code will be generated.

Note that `getter=getMyProp` is completely against the patterns of iOS and OS X programming.  Getters are not prefixed with `get`.

(2) `[object myProp]` and `object.myProp` are entirely equivalent at code generation time.  *However*, they are not equivalent during compilation prior to codeine.  The compiler will error on `object.myProp` if `object` is of type `id`.  That is, dot notation requires that the object in question be explicitly typed and definitely implements said method.

(3) Much of the sample code hasn't necessarily been updated and, given that the dot vs. bracketed syntax is interchangeable barring (2) (but you shouldn't be using `id` anyway), some till use brackets even in light of dot.

Comment: +1 It's nice to learn about the `retain` and `autorelease` when the implied `atomic` is used. Admittedly, I've been using `nonatomic` on all my properties.

Comment: Not sure about the second one. I would say it's the same (if the object type is id, then calling [object myProp] would give an error too, but not if you're calling [object performSelector:@selector(myProp)]. Anyway, according to Apple documentation, the lexical analyzer uses them both as the same, doesn't it?

Comment: @AlejandroIván Nope; not the same.  The dot requires a specific type (class or protocol) whereas using `id` with the bracketed syntax will compile without warning as long as the method is declared *somewhere*, *anywhere*, in any previously seen header file.

Comment: @bbum, thanks for the thorough answer. Regarding (1) if there is no underlying ivar then nonatomic doesn't matter at all, does it?

Comment: @mojuba Correct-- `nonatomic` does nothing if you manually implement the setter/getter.  I.e. `nonatomic` only matters when the methods are synthesized by the compiler.